# How to override methods of both ActionSupport & HttpServlet

Tags: java

I need to override methods of both ActionSupport & HttpServlet to my 
BaseSupport class. As a example I want to override below two methods in my base support class. Which means I need to extend both ActionSupport & HttpServlet class to my BaseSupport class

```
//From ActionSupport class
public void addActionError(String anErrorMessage) {
    this.validationAware.addActionError(anErrorMessage);
}

//From HttpServlet class
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //method body
}
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create one class that extends HttpServlet and an inner class that extends ActionSupport and you can use an instance of ActionSupport in this class. Beacuse java doesn't support multiple inheritance. Multiple inheritance is supported only interfaces.

```
<!-- language: java -->
public class BaseSupportServlet extends HttpServlet{

    private class CustomActionSupport extends ActionSupport{
        public void addActionError(String anErrorMessage) {
            this.validationAware.addActionError(anErrorMessage);
        }
    }

    private ActionSupport myActionSupport;

    public BaseSupportServlet(){
        myActionSupport = new CustomActionSupport();
    }

    //From HttpServlet class
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //method body
    }

    public void addActionError(String anErrorMessage) {
        myActionSupport.addActionError(anErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

Could this be a solution for you?

Comment: BaseSupportServlet is your class

Comment: What is CustomHttpServlet() method.. shoud it be constructor

Comment: validationAware' has private access in 'com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport

Comment: Then you can not use your parent class private variable, you may declare your own variable:
``private ValidationAwareSupport myValidationAware = new ValidationAwareSupport();``

and use this ``myValidationAware`` variable instead of ``this.validationAware``

Or you can call ``super.addActionError(anErrorMessage);`` then write your code extensions.

if you don't update method body it is meaningless using inheritance.